# how do i make users to download jpg files

Tags: php, network-programming

i need to make users download jpg files. i know that if i send them the link to the jpg file, the browser will just display the jpg file. Then the user must do rightclick -> save picture as

However, i want to force the download dialog box to appear so that they can download the jpg file. Anyone can help me with that?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to set the correct headers in your PHP script that serves the image to the user

```
header("Cache-Control: public");
header("Content-Description: File Transfer");
header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=$file");
header("Content-Type: image/jpg");
header("Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary");

//read image, write to user
```

Comment: `readfile($file);` is a good way to read & write the image file

Comment: $filename = file_get_contents("../mathieu-opticien-images/advertising/bigversion/Chrysanthemum.jpg"); header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=" . $filename); i tried it like this, it now says: Warning: Header may not contain more than a single header, new line detected. in D:\wamp\www\mathieu\includes\downloadjpg.php on line 9

Comment: You probably already printed a header somewhere. Debug your file (inspect the code, run it from console or attach a debugger) and see where the header was already sent.

Comment: @mahen23, I think what you needed to do is `$file = "../mathieu-opticien-images/advertising/bigversion/Chrysanthemum.jpg";` Instead, you're setting file name equal to the contents of the jpg image.

Comment: Well spotted. The filename just a string, so the user's browser knows how to name the file when he presents the download box to the user. No need for paths in the filename!

Comment: @Konerak, well spotted yourself. I know I've done this, but not something I do everyday so I need to look it up (perhaps in stackoverflow)